# Using iPhone/Objective C CGFloats: Is 0.1 okay, or should it be 0.1f?

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, core-graphics, double, cgfloat

When using an iPhone Objective C method that accepts `CGFloat`s, e.g. `[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:]`, is it important to append a f to constant arguments to specifiy them explicitly as floats, e.g. should I always type 0.1f rather than 0.1 in such cases? Or does the compiler automatically cast 0.1 (which is a double in general) to 0.1f (which is a float) at compile time? I don't wish to have these casts happen at run time because they would unneccessarily hog performance.

Thanks in advance

MrMage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *important*; it won't break anything to use a double-precision constant where a single-precision constant is expected.

However, if you have turned on the warning about implicit 64-bit-to-32-bit conversions and are building for 32-bit architectures (which I believe includes the iPhone), then you'll want to use single-precision constants simply to avoid getting that warning.

(Alternatively, you could set that setting to explicitly off, with an architecture condition turning it on for 64-bit architectures. But that *currently* only matters if you're also using some of your code in a Mac application.)

Comment: I know that nothing breaks, but when does the conversion from double to float occur? At compile time (would be fine) or at run time (then I'd add the f's)?

Comment: Thank you. Your comment is the real answer to my question. +1